# Replace letter in sourcedata of 250 Pivot tables

Tags: excel, replace, datasource

I had an issue while using Excel 2007 on a quite high size file. It recovered twice. I decided to save it locally before re-saving it onto the usual location on the server.
Doing so, I noticed that literally all my 250 or so Pivot tables's source data have been modified : the prefix 'X' drive has been replaced by 'C' automatically.

It is to be noted that each pivot table has its own sourcedata (link to a file) which differs necessarily from other pivot's source data. Basically, 1 pivot for each week.

Hence, what I need is quite simple : to replace the following String : 
"C:\"
by this one : 
"X:\"

Manually, it is feasible, but this really takes time has each time it refreshes pivot tables....and this has to be done 250 times....

Thanks for your help

Comment: describe the source data? How many rows?

Comment: is the source a table or a range?

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have ended up with this code :

```
Sub ChangePath()
```

Dim UnPCache As PivotCache
Dim memoCalcul As XlCalculation

```
Const OldPath As String = "C:\"
Const NewPath As String = "X:\"

memoCalcul = Application.Calculation

Application.Calculation = xlManual

 For Each UnPCache In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
          UnPCache.SourceData = Replace(UnPCache.SourceData, OldPath, NewPath, compare:=vbTextCompare)
Next

Application.Calculation = memoCalcul
End Sub
```

which actually returns a :
Run-time error 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error

always on the following line :

```
UnPCache.SourceData = Replace(UnPCache.SourceData, OldPath, NewPath, compare:=vbTextCompare)
```

Thanks for your kind help

Comment: Is it just a data cleanup issue, or do you have to do it programmatically? I would just treat the problem as a one off text cleanup.

Comment: Data is correct, it's just the sourcedata that have been replaced wrongly in the string and now point to incorrect files that don't exist.

Comment: Are you saying that the source data is fine, but everyone of 250 pivot tables has now got a fault in them, and that you want to alter the pivot tables?

Comment: No SourceData strings are incorrect due to the replacement of "X:\" by "C:\" in each sourcedata of all 250 Pivots.

Comment: Are you saying that each of the 250 pivots has it's own source data? Or are they all looking at the same source?

Comment: Yes exactly.1 specific source data for 1 pivot (basically 1 source data for 1 week database extract)

Comment: OK, so if there are then 250 sources, either as tables, or ranges, then that is where you must tackle it. It's nothing to do with the pivots. If the source data needs to be updated, in 250 seperate "datasets" then why not just do a "Find and replace"? IF I understand it right, you are just "repairing" the source data. A find "C:\" and replace with "X:\" will change everything in all cells, on every worksheet, if you select the correct paremeter in the dialog box. It's really not that complicated (26 seconds?)  unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: You are correct in terms of the contexte. However, the Replace dialog box 'Ctrl+H' usually does not allow to replace any character within Pivot Sourcedata...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple 3 step process.

1. Add a new column and put a formula in there to do it.
2. Copy and paste as numbers back over the original.
3. Delete the original column

If A1 contains `c:\xxxxx\xx\xx\x` then the formula is  `="X:\"&MID(A1,4,1000)`

If it's a table (not a range) the formula will auto replicate

Comment: Source data is not a table but a full string for Path [FileName] and a range

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if there are then 250 sources, either as tables, or ranges, then that is where you must tackle it. It's nothing to do with the pivots.

If the source data needs to be updated, in 250 seperate "datasets" then why not just do a "Find and replace"? If I understand it right, you are just "repairing" the source data.

A find "C:\" and replace with "X:\" will change everything in all cells, on every worksheet, if you select the correct paremeter in the dialog box.

Home tab > Editing > Find & Replace 
In the dialog box, click on "Options" to get more options
For the "Within" option, select "Workbook"

Find What:  C:\
Replace with:  X:\

Then "Replace All".

Should take about 1 minute end to end to sort out.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, Replace does not work for Pivot's Sourcedata. It only seems to work on cells content...Which sourcedata is not part of.
I did what you propose and funny enough it tells me that 7290 or so replacements were done...but actually none of them is related to what I was expecting

Comment: I'm really struggling to follow you here... I feel like I'm missing some critical piece of information. If you have done the 7,290 replacements, then have you refreshed your pivot tables? If it's something you are able to share, maybe pm me?